# Get task_struct from child after her termination

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Is there a way to get child's task_struct after it termination?

I need something like this:

```
long pid = sys_clone(CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND, 0);
if (pid > 0) {
        sys_wait4(-1, NULL, __WALL, NULL);
        //Get child's task_struct and check some values from it

} else {
       //child stuff.
}
```

Comment: I'd say no, as if the child terminated, that is had succefully been `wait()`ed on I'd expect the task to be gone.

Comment: i think that i can check if the child is a zombie before wait.
`//in parent
                        while(current->next->state != TASK_ZOMBIE) {
                        schedule();
                        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
                }
                //here, after zombie, but before sys_wait4
                i have acces to child task_struct
                sys_wait4(pid, &error, NULL, NULL);
`

Comment: You can call `waitid(2)` with the `WNOWAIT` flag to wait for the child but leave it in a waitable state (so the task struct is not deleted); then fetch the task struct, and finally reap its termination status with a regular wait.